# Why do I have to open my csv twice?

Tags: python, csv

Assume I have a csv file where I first need to get the number of rows in order to initialize an array. Then I want to fill the array with the rows from the file (but only some columns):

```
import csv
import numpy

with open('a_csv_file', 'rb') as f:
    num_row = sum(1 for row in f)
    myarray = numpy.empty(shape=(num_row, 50), dtype=numpy.int16)
    infileReader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in infileReader:
        row_number = infileReader.line_num - 1
        my_array[row_number] = [int(row[7])] + row[21:70]
```

However, the script doen't enter the row-loop. But `print infileReader` is confirms the existence of `infileReader`.

Now I open `a_csv_file.csv` twice, but I think that's not pythonic:

```
with open('a_csv_file', 'rb') as f:
    num_row = sum(1 for row in f)

myarray = numpy.empty(shape=(num_row, 50), dtype=numpy.int16)

with open('a_csv_file', 'rb') as f:
    infileReader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in infileReader:
        row_number = infileReader.line_num - 1
        my_array[row_number] = [int(row[7])] + row[21:70]
```

Why do I have to open the csv file twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through the file (to count the length), your position in the file is left at the end. When you try and iterate over it again, there is nothing left so the loop is not entered. Before you create the `csv.reader` call `f.seek(0)` to return to the start.

See the docs for the `seek` method [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file, you can't access twice to the same content. For instance, if you open a file, and use the method readLine() to read the first line, after it outputs, you're positioned in the second line, and cannot access to the first anymore.

When you do

```
num_row = sum(1 for row in f)
```

you're iterating through all the lines, leaving no data available for the csv reader.

To iterate twice all the lines could be a problem if the csv file was too heavy.

To avoid opening the file, you should first read it with csv.reader, and then use a parameter from the csv module to get the number of lines.

EDIT 1:

If the file isn't too big you can always do

```
file_rows = list(csv.reader(f))
num_row = len(rows)
for row in file_rows:
    # do something
```

Comment: Made a mistake, sorry. Edited posting an alternate solution